# RUN LARAVEL PROJECT MISSING .ENV FILE

Tags: laravel, github

How to run laravel project from github on localhost when .env file is missing in the laravel project?

Comment: There is a `.env.example` file available, rename it to `.env` and use it

Comment: sorry env.example is missing

Comment: Have you used composer to retrieve the vendor folder/.env.example?

Answer (score 3):

> You can rename the .env.example to .env and then run `php artisan
>   key:generate` and it'll function as it should.
>
> If you're using a command line simply type `cp .env.example .env` and
>   run the key:generate command.

If you are missing the .env files completely, you may take the .env.example file from: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/.env.example

Then simply create a new file named .env within your project. **You will still need to run php artisan key:generate once you have created the file.**

Comment: brother .env.example file is missing

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `.env.example`

Change the name with `.env`

Make your own settings in `.env` file.

After that run "`php artisan key:generate`"

Comment: brother .env.example is missing

Comment: You can copy by different project. Its not important.